# Is it possible to use object as invokable?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, requirejs-text

I found in [requirejs-text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text/blob/master/text.js#L155) weird code. So `load` method accepts `onLoad` callable which is invoked for a few times as `onLoad()`, but later there is error handler which checks for an error method.

```
if (onLoad.error) {
    onLoad.error(err);
}
```

Am i missing something or it's obvious code issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a normal object as a callable entity, but a function is a type of object, so you can add properties to a function.

```
var onLoad = function(){

};

onLoad.error = function(){

};
```